# Qt Creator 3.3.2: Moving views

Tags: qt-creator

In a previous version of Qt Creator (I don't know which one), I could drag and drop views.
In the version I currently use (3.3.2), this is apparently not possible.

Is it possible to move views in 3.3.2, and if so, how?

See below for what I want to achieve.

[image]

Also, a screenshot of my Windows -> Views menu.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable "automatically hide view title bars" in the Views menu from your second screenshot. Than you should have a title bar above each view which is draggable.